# Quick hints - show refactoring possibilties - extract to local variable

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

I'm moving from Eclipse to IntelliJ.
I have the Eclipse shortcuts in use for IntelliJ to feel at least a bit at home.

I miss the following in IntelliJ:
When cursor inside a string

- Eclipse: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> I have the option: "Extract to local variable"

  [image]
- IntelliJ: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> I don't have this option

  [image]

Yes, I could use  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> but would like to have this option as before.

Is it possible to customize this view?

Comment: Try using the Refactor This action.

Comment: ok you mean with my mentioned short or right click with mouse and refactor menu? 
Well would be great to have all possibilities with CTRL + 1 on your hand.